# Cucumber HTML Report

Tags: jenkins, cucumber

I am using cucumber.js and producing a .json report after an execution. I am executing my tests from a Jenkins which is not connected to any internet.
I am using cucumber-html-reporter to generate  the html report. The html report is created but the report on the Jenkins is not displayed correctly. Styles and css are broken as it is not able to download it.

Any way by which i can display the html report correctly without breaking images and styles on the Jenkins without having any access to internet. Or any other reporter which I can use to display the report correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you have added the dependency in your maven project to generate the reports. I believe you must check this plugin.

https://plugins.jenkins.io/cucumber-reports/

You can install the aforementioned plugin in your jenkins instance and then you can publish the json report with the help of this plugin. Otherwise you can create your custom html report by reading the required data from cucumber json report and once it is done, you can publish that html report in the jenkins.

It is even worthy to check the below jar file that I have created for the cucumber reporting.

https://github.com/frostyaxe/CucuReporter